# Suggestions bar with AccessoryView for Keyboard extension on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension, inputaccessoryview

Keyboard height, that available in Keyboard extension is to small for inserting suggestions bar there. I found that several users on AppDevForum offered to use `AccessoryView`. But for using it we need access to `TextField`, with seems as impossible, eventually now. So does someone know how to get that access or how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Apple's intention to not allow 3rd party keyboard to render beyond the default area, any hack way of doing it may cause rejections during app review... But try UITextDocumentProxy see if you can access text view from it?